# Finding solution of nonlinear differential system

Tags: nonlinear-system

$$x'=2x+y^2$$
$$y'=y$$

How to find a solution of above system if $x>0$?

I found a solution of second equation, $y=y_0e^t$, but don't know how to use this to solve the system. Thanks.

Comment: You first equation becomes $x' - 2x= (y_0)^2 e^{2t}.$    Now use an integrating factor $e^{-2t}.$

Comment: @mattbiesecker Ah, thank you so much. I get it now. then, there is no general solving method to arbitrary nonlinear system?

Comment: No.  In general,  non-linear systems to admitting exact solutions are in a sense exceptional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x'-2x=y^2$$
$$x'-2x=(y_0)^2e^{2t}$$
the characteristic equation for homogeneous D.E 
$$m-2=0$$ 
$$m=2$$
the complementary solution of $x$
$$x_c=C_1e^{2t}$$
so the particular solution 
$$x_p=Ate^{2t}$$
and then find the value of $A$